# An asymptotic formula for a nested radical

Tags: asymptotics, nested-radicals

Consider a nested radical (written with exponents) of the form:

$$F(n,k,q)=\left(k^n+\left(k^{n+1}+\left(k^{n+2}+\left(k^{n+3}+\cdots\right)^{1/q}\right)^{1/q}\right)^{1/q}\right)^{1/q}$$

I have observed that as $n\to\infty$, we have 
$$F(n,k,q)\sim k^{\frac{n}{q}}+\frac1q k^{\frac{1+n(2-q)}{q}}$$

How can we prove that this asymptotic is true?

Comment: How did you observe that?

Comment: By messing around and generalizing things. For example when $k=3$, $q=2$ I could see the decimal expansion of $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ after a whole number emerging. I made a guess and generalized it and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, notice the recursion $\;F(n,k,q) = (k^n\!+\!F(n\!+\!1,k,q))^{1/q}\;$ which we use in the following.

For simplicity let $z := k^{1/q},\; y := z/k,\; x := y^nz.\;$ Define, by recursion, the sequence $\;a_i(t)\;$ with
$\;a_0(t) := 1 + O(t),\;$ and $\;a_{i+1}(t) := (1 + q\;t\; a_i(ty))^{1/q}.\;$ Thus, we get $\;a_1(t) = 1 + t + O(t^2),\;$
$\;a_2(t) = 1 + t + (1-q+2y)t^2/2! + O(t^3),\;$ and so on. Now, the asymptotic formula is, for all $i$,
$F(n,k,q) \sim z^n a_i(x/q).\;$ For  $i=1,\;$ it is
$k^{n/q}(1 + x/q + O(x^2)) = k^{\frac{n}{q}}(1 + \frac1q k^{\frac{n+1}{q}-n}+O(x^2)).$

Your nested radical is also called a continued radical and they have a long history.

Edit: An example computation using [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) looks like this:

```
? nxt(at) = (1 + q*t*subst(at,t,t*Y))^(1/q);
? a0 = 1 + O(t); a1 = nxt(a0); a2 = nxt(a1);
? print("a0 = ",a0); print("a1 = ",a1); print("a2 = ",a2);
a0 = 1 + O(t)
a1 = 1 + t + O(t^2)
a2 = 1 + t + (-1/2*q + (Y + 1/2))*t^2 + O(t^3)
```

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: Do you think you could help me define the sequence $a_i (t)$ in closed form with asymptotic notation?  It looks like a power series but I don't know enough analysis to complete it.  Should I ask in a new question?

Comment: @user991003: I am not sure what you mean. I seriously doubt that "closed form" is possible for $a_i(t).$ Yes, it is the exponential generating function of a sequence of polynomials in $q$ and $y.$ What **is** possible is to use the recursion to produce successive terms of it.

Comment: okay, what i guess i don't understand is how you produced the successive terms using the big oh notation.  If we use the recursion directly to derive successive terms, they are not the same as the ones you've shown... so I'm just missing something.

Comment: @user991003; Please see my new edit with PARI/GP code.